# Python - sending HTML Mail with Variables

Tags: python, html, email, string-formatting

I wanted to make a small cronmailer for my personal use. And here's the part wich do not work

```
# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "LOG OUTPUT: " + sys.argv[1] + "\n"
logdata = open(sys.argv[2], "rb") 
for row in logdata:
        text = text + row

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>LOG OUTPUT: {0} <br> {1} 
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
""".format(unicode(str(sys.argv[1]),'utf-8'),  unicode(str(logdata),'utf-8'))


part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

server = smtplib.SMTP(str(server) + ":" + str(port))
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(emailfrom, emailto, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

I get the mail. With the Plain Text and the attachment (left the code out, cause it works). But not the HTML part. The only thing I get there is:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>LOG OUTPUT: test
```

Thanks for any help and a Happy New Year

Comment: I can't help but notice that the output ends right where the `<br>` element that you didn't close starts. If you're lucky, changing that to `<br />` might actually solve your problem.

Comment: You want to include content of the file? afaik, unicode(str(logdata),'utf-8') doesn't return the content of the file

Comment: @FrEaKmAn how can i add the content of the file right into the HTML ? it only contains text.

Comment: Read the file with logdata.read().

Comment: @FrEaKmAn unicode(logdata.read(),'utf-8') also breaks the html  there is no HTML TAG left anymore.

Comment: @SvenBamberger, you have "the content of the file" in variable `text` (obtained very laboriously when a `.read()` as suggested by FrEaKmAn would be simpler, but, that's a detail) -- so escape and insert it.  Escaping is important and you're not doing it now!  You're inserting a string such as `"<open file 'foo.txt', mode 'rb' at 0x109a08810>"` and those unescaped angle brackets no doubt cause your problem...

Comment: @AlexMartelli how do i escape them? I also tried unicode(logdata.read(),'utf-8') but this also don't work

Comment: In Python 3, escaping is done w/the standard library module `html`, function `html.escape`; in Python 2, the module is `cgi` and the function `cgi.escape` -- unfortunate naming (fixed in Py3) but same functionality.

Comment: BTW, since the text includes newlines and you probably want to see them, be sure to include it within a `<pre> ... </pre>` tag.

Comment: @AlexMartelli could you please give me an example? I don't know what you mean

Comment: I'd better make this into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are likely-better ways to build that html string (in Python 2):

```
import cgi

text = "LOG OUTPUT: " + sys.argv[1] + "\n"
with open(sys.argv[2], "rb") as f:
    text += f.read()

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>LOG OUTPUT: {0}<br/>
    <pre>{1}</pre>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>""".format(unicode(str(sys.argv[1]), 'utf-8'),
                  unicode(cgi.escape(text), 'utf-8'))
```

Note that in Python 3 the escaping function is `html.escape` (so you'd better not name your own variable `html` as it will clash:-), but for Python 2, where the escaping function is the peculiarly named `cgi.escape`, this should be OK.

Comment: Just modified this  
   <p>LOG OUTPUT: {0}<br/>
        <pre>{1}</pre>

into 

<p><pre>{0}</pre>

to Prevent double lined LOG OUTPUT: XXXX